# Stray "html" start tag

Tags: java, html, servlets

Working on my servlet project. In index.html file i have *Stray "html" start tag* error. Problem is somewere in this part of code:

```
<%@ page contentType = "text/html"; charset = "UTF-8" language = "java"%>
<html>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public.styles/style.css">
</head>
<body>
```

Maybe someone see how to fix it?

Comment: So why do you have an JSP tag in your .html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `jsp` tags in `html`
 I think there are some mistakes in this.

**in jsp-**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
```

**in html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

What's your needs?

- If you want to write a jsp file, your file must have a "jsp" extension, like : index.jsp, and you can include html content inside.
- Otherwise, il you want an html file, your file extension should be .html